# Get-MailboxPermission and Get-ADPermission command does not work with Get-RemoteMailbox command

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, powershell-remoting

I am trying to use this command but it does not provide any output or error

```
Get-RemoteMailbox | Get-MailboxPermission -user $user | Where {($_.AccessRights -like "FullAccess") -and -not ($_.User -eq "NT AUTHORITY\SELF")} | Select Identity,User
```

*Note: We have Hybrid Exchange Setup we have on-prem and Office 365 Exchange both*

Answer (score 1):

`Get-MailboxPermission` is an On-Permise cmdlet and will work only for OnPremise Mailbox and not on a `Remote-Mailbox`, you should connect to 365 Remote Exchange Shell and execute it from there:

```
$Cred = Get-Credential
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $Cred -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
Import-PSSession $Session -WarningAction SilentlyContinue -DisableNameChecking
```

And Then:

```
Get-Mailbox | Get-MailboxPermission -user $user | Where [...]
```

**Note**: Dont execute it on your OnPremise Exchange Server Shell, it will confilict with the existing exchange commands...

Comment: Get-MailboxPermission command does not exist in my PowerShell session that's the main thing I am looking for a resolution

Comment: This is regular exchange command, did you try to login using my code snippet?

Comment: Yes, I did finally I got it figured out I have to connect with Azure and then Install the Exchange Online module from the Exchange Hybrid portion and then Connect with Exchange Online and then run the command I specified but without the Remote in it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!!